# Capturing/Using Data from API (XML/Python)

Tags: python, php, xml

So I am teaching myself how to do a bit of programming and I have run into a wall. I hope this kind of vague questioning is allowed as I am so lost as to where to go next.

**Objective:** Call an API, get a specific set of data from said API (it comes back in XML format) and either save it into a database or display the data directly onto a PHP webpage.

**What I've Done:**
I can reach the API & pass authorization. I get an XML file in return and can parse it. I've also been able to isolate 1, of 3, elements. I can also connect to a locahost DB.

**What I need to do** 1) run a loop so that the program pulls all data of a specific element versus just the first matching element. I also need to put the data into a database (I assume but not sure if that's necessary), and then finally display the specific data on a PHP page.

Python

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from mysql.connector import (connection)
import MySQLdb

with urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.zillow.com/webservice/ProReviews.htm?zws-id=X1-ZWz16k2mlna5fv_6ikyi&screenname=robertbaileybp') as url:
    s = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')
review = soup.find_all('review')
soup.encode("utf8")
print(soup)

conn = mysql.connector.connect(user="root", password="password", host="localhost", database="brReview")

print(conn)
```

PHP

```
<?PHP
include 'header.php'
?>

<container>
   <row>
      <col>
         Insert data from API here.
      </col>
   </row>
</container>

<?PHP
include 'footer.php'
?>
```

I'm not looking for the whole thing written for me but rather pointed into the direction of what needs to be done next. What sort of libraries or tools can be used to complete the tasks above. TIA

Comment: Why would you not just do it all in PHP, if that's the final destination?

Comment: Please ask about one specific problem at a time. "What I need to do" looks like it can be split into three separate questions. Also note that questions asking for tool or library recommendations are off-topic.